# UITableView not dequeuing some cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've never run into this issue before, but here is what I am currently experiencing:

I have a UITableView in a view controller. Delegate and dataSource are setup properly.
Now I'm running into performance issues after showing/inserting a few cells.
The issue is that the tableview seems to not dequeue some of the cells but rather creates a new one each time (always calls awakeFromNib in the custom class).

The ones with which the dequeuing seems to not work are just simple ones with a label and some with a label, an image and another label.
There is however one case in which dequeuing seems to work. I have a custom cell class that just contains a vertical stack view into which I dynamically add a variable amount of custom buttons.

I have a class that is responsible for setting up the cells. It has a method for each of the cell classes I use.

```
func initialModeratorCell(at indexPath: IndexPath, with message: Message, in tableView: UITableView) -> OnboardingInitialModeratorCell{
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: initalModeratorCellIndentifier) as? OnboardingInitialModeratorCell else{
        fatalError("No cell with \(initalModeratorCellIndentifier) identifier")
    }

    if indexPath.row != 0{
        cell.moderatorImage.isHidden = true
    }

    let attributedMessage = attributedString(for: message, with: paragraphStyleFor(message: message))
    cell.mesageText.attributedText = attributedMessage
    cell.dateLabel.text = message.userType.name()
    cell.mesageText.sizeToFit()
    cell.dateLabel.sizeToFit()

    return cell
}
```

All those methods look similar to this. This is one that doesn't seem to get reused.

This here is the one that does get reused (`awakeFromNib` only called once):

```
func componentCell(from item: ConversationItem, in tableView: UITableView, with owner: OnboardingComponentCellDelegate) -> OnboardingComponentCell{

    guard let comp = item as? Component else{
        fatalError("Type of item is not Component, but should be!")
    }

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: componentButtonsCellIdentifier) as? OnboardingComponentCell else{
        fatalError("No cell with \(componentButtonsCellIdentifier) identifier")
    }
    cell.componentStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    setupComponentCell(cell, for: comp, owner: owner)
    return cell;

}
```

This is `setupCell()`:

```
setupComponentCell(_ cell: OnboardingComponentCell, for comp: Component, owner: OnboardingComponentCellDelegate){
    cell.reset()
    cell.component = comp
    OnboardingComponentManager.createComponent(for: comp, in: cell, delegate: owner)
}
```

The `cell.reset()` method looks like this:

```
func reset(){
    component = nil
    delegate = nil
    componentStack.removeAll() //removeAll is in an extension on UIStackView
}
```

The call `OnboardingComponentManager.createComponent()` just populates the stackview with the correct buttons for said component.

The methods above (`componentCell(from:)` and `initialModeratorCell(at:)` are called from the public method `onboardingCellForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath, ..)`:

```
static func onboardingCellForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath, with displayedItems: Items, in tableView: Table, typingDelegate: IndicatorDelegate, buttonOwner: CellDelegate, onboardingType: ConvType) -> UITableViewCell{

    let item = displayedItems[indexPath.row]
    if item.type == .message{
        return messageCell(from: item, at: indexPath, in: tableView, with: displayedItems)
    }else if item.type == .component{
        return componentCell(from: item, in: tableView, with: buttonOwner)
    }else if item.type == .typingIndicator{
        return typingIndicatorCell(with: typingDelegate, in: tableView)
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

This method then is called from the dataSource method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return OnboardingCellManager.onboardingCellForItem(at: indexPath, with: displayedItems, in: tableView, typingDelegate: self, buttonOwner: self, onboardingType: .onboarding)
}
```

The cells were prototyped in a storyboard in the tableView (as prototype cells).

I'm somewhat hitting a wall here. I've never run into this issue before and I can't seem to find the reason as to why it happens.
This performance degradation is most notable on older devices (iPhone 5, etc).

Comment: Probably unrelated, if you use `dequeueReusableCell` with the identifier and the index path (not just the identifier), that returns a non-optional. There's an outside chance that this affects the dequeue logic, too.

Comment: In terms of diagnosing this, it's hard to do so without seeing how the `UITableViewDataSource` methods call the above. Ideally, we'd like to see a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because until we can reproduce the problem, it's hard to advise you how to fix it.

Comment: @Rob I tried to use that too, but it didn't help mitigate the issue

Comment: @Rob Regarding the dataSource: The class responsible for creating the cells (the one the methods in the question come from) has one public method `onboardingCellForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath, with displayedItems: Items, in tableView: Table, typingDelegate: IndicatorDelegate, buttonOwner: CellDelegate, onboardingType: ConvType) ` which then, based on the item's type for the cell creates the different cells.

I'll try and elaborate on that in the question some more, though I'm not sure how easily I'll be able to provide a MCVE

Comment: A few clarifying questions: Is the issue that it's not dequeuing like you'd expect (e.g. just because a cell just scrolled out of view, it doesn't mean that it is immediately available for dequeuing), or that it's never dequeuing? Is the cell ever getting released? I assume that `componentButtonsCellIdentifier` is a constant, not a variable: Is that right?

Comment: Correct, its a constant, as are the others like `initalModeratorCellIndentifier`.

What I meant is that if I set breakpoints in awakeFromNib in all those custom cell classes, the ones in those message-type cells always get called, the one for component-type cells only on the first one (even if the cell then is removed/replaced by another cell).

I also see a steady increase in memory the more message-cells get inserted into the tableview, which leads me to believe its always creating the messages cell new.

Comment: is this issue like if you are having label in cell but sometimes label text doesn't appear but cell next to it with label shows Text ?

Comment: @iOSGeek No. What I'm seeing is, one, that some of my cells (namely those that represent a message) don't seem to get reused but created new every time. And two, it seems that depending on how bad it gets, the tableview seems to swallow some of those message cells. As in, they seem to appear but then get replaced with one of the component ones when those come on screen.

An as mentioned, it gets worse over time, it works fine at the beginning.

Comment: please can you share a screenshot when it get worst ?

Comment: Can't, for company reasons. But I'll try to describe it. I'm basically doing an automated onboarding that inserts "messages" from a moderator one after the other (with short delays and typing indication in between). When it gets worse, the tableview begins to jump weirdly when messages/cells get inserted, and as mentioned sometimes messages that should appear just disappear/get replaced by the next. It seems to be a combo of memory issue and timing, most likely

Comment: @iOSGeek I've been looking into it a little more over the day and it seems like it is more of a memory leak/retain cycle issue, since the memory graph in Xcode shows me some of those very objects involved (Model objects and dictionaries) seem go leak/have retain cycles.